# What are the YAML keywords that can be used in RobotFramework for editing YAML file?

Tags: python, yaml, robotframework

I tried editing YAML file and I came across only few keywords that can be used for editing dictionary values of YAML file. But I need to edit list values in YAML file as well. So, where can I get all the keywords list which can be used for editing YAML file using robot framework?

Example: 1. Below is the sample YAML file

```
"patch_id_bw_data":
    "pronghornResponseBody":
        "shimBehaviourHeader":
            "destinationURL": ""
            "method": "PATCH"
            "targetName": "naas"
        "customHeaders": {}
        "responseBody":
            - "op": "replace"
              "path": "/serviceCharacteristic"
              "value":
                  - "name": "bandwidth"
                    "value": ""
```

2. Here is the code for editing dictionary values. Same I want to do for list as well.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  yaml
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Load YAML into Robot and edit it
  ${YAML}=  Get File  ${CURDIR}${/}data.yaml
  ${LOADED}=  yaml.Safe Load  ${YAML}
  Set To Dictionary  ${LOADED}[patch_id_bw_data][pronghornResponseBody][responseBody][0][value][0]  value=200
  ${OUTPUT}=  yaml.Dump  ${LOADED}
  Create File  newdata.yaml  ${OUTPUT}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Set List Value", per [The Collections Library Documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/2.1.2/libraries/Collections.html). You're not really editing YAML.  Rather, you're modifying a collection that happened to have been read from a YAML file.  Refer to the docs for other manipulations you can perform on collections.

Comment: Thanks for the information Steve! This will help me in doing other manipulations as well